# WCF Service Method POST and GET in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services

i have a two program, first the asp.net and the second is WCF Service.
the code below is on asp.net program.

```
Public Function GetDataSource(ByVal prmModule As Object, ByVal prmEndPointName As String)
    Dim strEndPoint As String = GetEndPoint(prmEndPointName)
    Dim wr As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strEndPoint & prmModule)
    Dim ws As WebResponse = wr.GetResponse
    Dim enc As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
    Dim rs As New StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream)
    Dim response As String = rs.ReadToEnd
    rs.Close()
    Return response
End Function

Public Sub SendClientData(ByVal prmEndPoint As String, ByVal prmModule As String, ByVal prmSource As String)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim address As Uri
    Dim data As StringBuilder
    Dim byteData() As Byte
    Dim postStream As Stream = Nothing

    ' Set the REST API URL
    address = New Uri(GetEndPoint(prmEndPoint) & prmModule)
    ' Create the web request
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)

    ' Set type to POST  
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    ' Create the data we want to send (each data.Append is for specific paramater data) 
    data = New StringBuilder()
    data.Append(prmSource)
    ' Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
    byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString())

    ' Set the content length in the request headers  
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Try
        postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
        postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    Finally
        If Not postStream Is Nothing Then postStream.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

the above code is the function, GetDataSource is used to GET Method and the SendClientData is used to POST Method.

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", _
       ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, _
       BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, _
       UriTemplate:="applicant/post")> _
Sub postApplicant(ByVal request As Stream)

<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", _
       ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, _
       BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, _
       UriTemplate:="applicant/search/{firstname}/{lastname}/{dateofbirth}/{placeofbirth}")> _
Function getApplicantHaermes(ByVal firstname As String, ByVal lastname As String, ByVal dateofbirth As String, ByVal placeofbirth As String) As String
```

the code above is on WCF Service, its used to call the function that implemented.

here's the main question:

```
        Dim arr As New ArrayList : arr.Add("Id")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim tempDT As New DataTable
        tempDT = (AddPhoneNumberToDataTable(obj))
        If Session("EditPhoneNumber") IsNot Nothing Then
            SendClientData(EMPLOYEEENDPOINT, "phonenumber/postupdate/" &                   obj.HaermesOid, GetJsonFromDataTable(tempDT))
        Else
            SendClientData(EMPLOYEEENDPOINT, "phonenumber/post", GetJsonFromDataTable(tempDT))

            dt = AssignToDataTable(GetDataSource("phonenumber/search/" & obj.Party.Oid.ToString & "/" & obj.PhoneType.ToString & _
                                             "/" & obj.Number.ToString, EMPLOYEEENDPOINT), arr)

            With obj
                .HaermesOid = dt(0)("Id")
                .Save()
            End With
        End If
```

when i call the SendClientData from ASP.Net to call WCF service for posting some data, the code below (Function GetDataSoucre) is for Get data from WCF to ASP.Net, but when i call the SendClientData the function that implemented is running, its not even finished yet then the GET Function already running, its make two function running at the same time. The GET Method is getting the data from the POST Method, so in the end the GET Method didn't get the data.